# Struggling to find a recently seen answer for the life of me; what could be the problem?

Tags: support

I recently read an answer to one of my questions on law. SE which mentioned (and linked to, on legislation.gov.uk) the tenant fees act 2019 (in one way or another, not sure, for example, if it bothered to specify the legislation's year) toward the end of it. I was really reading the answer just earlier this morning and it must have been posted in the last 18 hours if not in the last 8. Now, for the life of me, checking my entire inbox and going down the main list of recently active questions on the home page and reading all their answers I'm not able to find it. I've searched for about an hour.

Can anyone offer any suggestions or insights  as to why I may not be finding out or how I could?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might have been a comment by JBentley made under [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/82951/35069) that was [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138416/discussion-on-answer-by-jbentley-where-is-the-line-between-an-assured-shorthold) (and misspelled as the *Tenancy* Fees Act 2019)

Comment: Isn't tenancy the correct spelling though?

Comment: And do chats expire? For some reason I'm getting an error claiming the the moved to chat link under that answer is broken.

Comment: @JosephP. The link works okay for me, and yes that is the correct spelling of *tenancy* but the legislation is the [**Tenant** Fees Act 2019](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2019/4/contents)

Comment: I just continually get "This page isn't available. The link that you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."

Comment: @JosephP. Consider raising a "something else" flag for a Mod to investigate. Feel free to raise it from this comment so they get the background info

Comment: I've just tried it from a computer though and it works so maybe it's my network provider or something like that.